# Using removeAll to remove a sublist from a list

Tags: java, list, collections, removeall

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(0);
    list.removeAll(list.subList(0, 1));
    System.out.println(list);
```

If I run this code, it gives [0].

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);
    list.removeAll(list.subList(0, 1));
    System.out.println(list);
```

This gives [0, 1]...

Why are they different? More importantly, why it gives [0] in the first case?

Comment: The behaviour looks strange as subList is actually a view of part of the original list. Which is will be affected during removeAll. You can get expected behaviour like         `list.removeAll(List.copyOf(list.subList(0, 1)));`

Comment: the `subList()` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,int)) gives a solution: `list.subList(from, to).clear();`

Comment: The modCount of backing array is updated.As rightly mentioned,the sublist returns a view of the list so a ConcurrentModification exception is raised if you debug through removeAll method. While iterating to sublist view, element is being removed in  removeall iteration.